# How to import a csv file with date in matlab and plot it?

Tags: matlab, plot, fopen, textscan

I have a csv file that has two columns, date and float, the date format is weird though (Jan 1 2016 9:55:00 PM), how can I import it to matlab and draw it as a plot? this is what i tried:

```
fid = fopen('all.csv');
if fid>0    
     data = textscan(fid,'%s %d','Delimiter',',');
     % close the file
     fclose(fid);         
end
x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);

plot(x,y);
```

but i get an error not enough arguments

Sample of all.csv:

```
Jan 1 2016 9:55:00 PM, 12493829,
Jan 2 2016 7:55:00 AM, 83747283,
Jan 3 2016 2:55:00 PM, 89572948,
Jan 4 2016 8:55:00 AM, 95862744,
```

the error:

```
Error using plot
Not enough input arguments.

Error in test (line 10)
plot(x,y);
```

Comment: @SardarUsama Done.

Comment: my bad, i wanted to make it `%D %d` i thought %D is date but turns out i need to specify the format which is my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears since you're inputting cell arrays in the `plot` function.

```
x = data{:,1};   %You need { } here, not ()
y = data{:,2};

plot(1:numel(x), y, 'o-');
%Ensuring the xticks are as required and changing the xticklabels to datetime values and 
%rotating the labels for better visualisation ('xticklabelrotation' requires >= R2014b)
set(gca,'xtick',1:numel(x),'xticklabel',x,'xticklabelrotation',45);
```

*Output:*

[image: output]

Comment: Works perfect. I tested it with the sample i posted, but the data I have has three million rows, I am using the online compiler and it is not showing any figures, maybe because it is huge, once I get home i will test it on my matlab on laptop, do you think it will work for 3 million rows?

Comment: @Abdane It will but I don't know how you'll be able to obtain any useful information from the plot made with that many rows

Comment: that's fine, ill test it when i get home, quick question, how can I remove the time from my string? I just need to show the date without the time. is there any substring equivalent in Matlab> im new, sorry

Comment: found it, extractBefore(str, int); thanks anyways :)

Comment: unfortunately it didnt work with 3mil rows, is there any other approach you think i can use?

Comment: I ran it, it ends and nothing happens, no plot is shown

Comment: do you get anything if you don't use the last line?

Comment: Yea i do, but damn the graph is ugly, haha, looks like a barcode :P
It was very different with excel

Comment: seems like you need better graphics. and very likely not a programming issue. plot a small version of data that you need to visualise at one moment instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
fid = fopen('all.csv');
if fid>0    
     data = textscan(fid,'%s %d','Delimiter',',');
     % close the file
     fclose(fid);         
end
x = datenum( data(:,1),'mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:SS PM');Convert it to a compatoble format before
y = data(:,2);
plot(x,y);
datetick('x','dd.mm.yyyy','keepticks') %Makes the x axis numbers to dates
```

Comment: Sorry, of cource it is "data(:,1)"